# How to Set image upload to only jpg and png Files?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is the code i am using it works great but how to i only set the files types to jpg and png and disallow/ not display any other images in the gallery

```
private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    Intent = new Intent();
    Intent.SetType("image/*");
    Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
}

#endregion

#region Get the Path of Selected Image
private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri) {
    string path = null;
    // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
    string[] projection = new[] { 
            Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
    using (ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null)) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
        }
    }
    return path;
}
#endregion

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
    // For single image Selection
    if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null)) {
        Uri uri = data.Data;
        _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);
        path = GetPathToImage (uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think all the given answers are wrong. Requirement is to allow both jpg and png Files. This allows only to select given file types.

First Create mimeTypes array including all the allow file types.

Then put it in intent extras.

Here is the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
String [] mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg","image/jpeg"};
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_GET_SINGLE_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `Intent.setType("image/jpg");` instead of `Intent.setType("image/*");`

Answer (score 0):

Use setType for jpeg

`intent.setType("image/jpeg")` or `intent.setType("image/jpg")`

or for png

`intent.setType("image/png")`

Comment: but how do i allow oth jpg and png? only those format and nothing else?

Comment: but also when i was trying this, when i set it to intent.setType("image/jpg") it still allowed other formats to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for answering, but the solution which worked for me I just want to share.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // opens shared file explorer
    galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};  // /jpeg will support both jpg and jpeg files
    galleryIntent.setType("image/jpeg|image/png");  // I had to include both setType and putExtra for my code to work correctly
    galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    pickImageFromGalleryForResult.launch(galleryIntent);  // you can replace this line with your startActivityForResult() here
```

Try it out and tell me if it works for your use case.